# Error message I get, cant figure out the problem. Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#

I am new to ASP.net and I need help.

I try to add new entity to the DB and I get the following error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.dll

Reading here I guess it is something to do with the connection string but I can figure out what it is

Here is my code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO user_master_table " +
                "fullname,birthday,email,phone,address,teamname,shirtnumber,hight,weight,userID,password) " +
                "values(" +
                "@fullname,@birthday,@email,@phone,@address,@teamname,@shirtnumber,@hight,@weight,@userID,@password)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", TextBoxFullName.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthday", TextBoxBirthday.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", Email.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBoxAddress.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teamname", DropDownListTeamID.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shirtnumber", TextBoxShirtNumber.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hight", TextBoxHeight.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weight", TextBoxWeight.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", TextBoxUserID.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPassword.Text.Trim());
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_status", "pending");

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Sign Up Successful. Go to User Login to Login');</script>");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
        }
    }
```

`Web.config` connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="con" 
         connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-6S13RTK\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BasketBallDB;Intergrated Security=true" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I try to figure out what do you mean,

Comment: @marc_s 1 that was a typo mistake in the webconfig,  2 i retype the insert and hope it will fix the issue,  many thanks for your quick answer

Comment: @marc_s Many thanks, you solved it for me.

Comment: If you my answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept the answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your `web.config` (`Intergrated Security` should be `Integrated Security`):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="con" 
         connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-6S13RTK\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BasketBallDB;Integrated Security=true" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And your `INSERT` statement is incomplete - you're missing the leading `(` for the list of columns:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO user_master_table " +
                                // here, before the first column name - add "(" ...
                                "(fullname, birthday, email, phone, address, teamname, shirtnumber, height, weight, userID, password) " +
                                "VALUES (" +
                                "@fullname, @birthday, @email, @phone, @address, @teamname, @shirtnumber, @height, @weight, @userID, @password)", con);
```

And the column (and variable) should probably be `height` (not `hight`) ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code was missing the opening parenthesis `(` before the column list (before the `fullname` column, in your case) in the `SqlCommand`.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO user_master_table " +
                "(fullname,birthday,email,phone,address,teamname,shirtnumber,hight,weight,userID,password) " +
                "values(" +
                "@fullname,@birthday,@email,@phone,@address,@teamname,@shirtnumber,@hight,@weight,@userID,@password)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", TextBoxFullName.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthday", TextBoxBirthday.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", Email.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBoxAddress.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teamname", DropDownListTeamID.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shirtnumber", TextBoxShirtNumber.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hight", TextBoxHeight.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weight", TextBoxWeight.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", TextBoxUserID.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPassword.Text.Trim());
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_status", "pending");

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Sign Up Successful. Go to User Login to Login');</script>");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
        }
    }
```